# Footer not aligning to bottom of screen when position absolute is used

Tags: css

I'm having problems getting my footer to stick to the bottom of the page when there are position absolute elements in the main container. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ymVgj/) to demonstrate.

```
<div class="content-wraper">
    <div class="side-nav"></div>
</div>

<div class="footer"></div>​
```

```css
.content-wraper {
    background-color:blue;
    min-height:100px;
    position:relative;
    width:500px;
}

.side-nav {
    background-color:red;
    height:3000px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:200px;
}

.footer {
    background-color:black;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
}
```

Comment: Do you want the footer to stick to the bottom of the viewport at all times, or the bottom of the page itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `position: absolute;` in `.footer` to `position: fixed;`

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ymVgj/2/)

---

**UPDATE**

To fix the footer to always be below the absolutely positioned `side-nav` using jQuery try this:

```
$(".footer").css("top", $(".side-nav").height());
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ymVgj/3/)

Comment: I dont want it fixed though

Comment: Really? Your question reads as though you do. What do you want it to do?

Comment: I want it to be at the bottom of the page not the window. So under all the rest of the content

Comment: That won't be possible with the HTML markup you have. You would need to put the footer inside the sidebar.

Comment: thats not what i'm after, is it possible to use javascript to achieve my goal?

Comment: It's possible, but you really shouldn't use javascript for layout purposes, that's what HTML and CSS is for.

Answer (score 1):

absolute positioning refers to window size, not content size, so if content is higher than window, you won't get the effect you want.

Try different approach:

[sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)

Comment: problem is i need the side nav to be absolute

Comment: you still can do it with this approach